# Netlogo: how to color a patch only when a turtle is on it?

Tags: colors, netlogo

I'm trying to write some code that would color a patch only when a turtle is on that specific patch. Otherwise, the patch would be it's original color. I want this to occur as the turtle moves, so a turtle colors a patch red then as it moves forward, the patch it just colored red would be reverted back to it's original color. Thanks!

Comment: I’m sure there are better ways to do it but my first thought would be in the vein of “ask patches [ifelse (count[turtles] > 0) set color red, set color green]. Pretty sure there’s a syntax error in that line but point being use an ifelse statement to tell all patches to set their color red if they have a turtle, and the original color of not. If you put it at the end of your go statement it will color it after the turtles move.

Answer (score 2):

The comment by @Jesse001 is on the right track. Try this:

```
ask patches [ set pcolor ifelse-value any? turtles-here [red] [green] ]
```

or the slightly easier to read equivalent:

```
ask patches
[ ifelse-value any? turtles-here
  [ set pcolor red]
  [ set pcolor green]
]
```

If you want it directly tied to the turtle's movement, then you can use `[ ask patch-here [ set pcolor red ] ]` in the movement part of the code. Have it set the colour just before it moves and just after. Of course, you will have to make sure there aren't any other turtles on the same patch before switching to the colour for empty.

Comment: Hi, I tried implementing what you suggested but it didn't execute the way I wanted. Heres what I have so far:                                                                               `to go
   every .1 [ 
  ask turtle 0 [ 
 fd carspeed
  ask patch-ahead 1 [set pcolor red]
  ask patch-ahead 0 [set pcolor brown]]
   play ]
end `

Comment: However, this code only works on a certain interval. I have a slider that control "carSpeed" and it works only with the slider at 1.

Comment: Edit your question to add more details. You need to provide relevant code, explain what you want and what the code is doing instead. Code is almost unreadable in comments.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving the problem by calling the procedure repeatedly on my go procedure so it would consistently color the patches while including the code to turn the patch-ahead red. Thanks for everyone's help!